# Jenkinsfile escape % to not be treated as a variable

Tags: windows, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, escaping

I have Jenkinsfile which is meant to be run a Windows 10 agent and i have the following situation on my Jenkinsfile. I want to run this command inside a bat step:

```
python myscript.py job/release%252F2.2.0
```

When the command get execute, the argument is transformed to `job/release52F2.2.0` . For some reason %2 is treated as a variable, an empty one, which is not what i want.
Anyone know how i could force during execution to not replace the %2 and just leave it as is.

I tried adding a \ in front, but it just throws an error since it is not expected.

Anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself, apparently i need to use double % in order to make it work. So final command looks like :

```
python myscript.py job/release%%252F2.2.0
```